# como guardar um post na variavel na mesma pagina

Tags: php

galera e o seguinte tenho um campo number na minha pagina e quero pegar ele e mandar o valor digitado nele na mesma pagina como que eu posso pegar o valor digitado nele na mesma pagina sem usar jquery ou javascript quero pegar o valor dele por php preciso pegar este valor e imediatamente passar na mesma pagina como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Juro que tentei entender, mas não consegui.

Comment: Era melhor não comentar a sua dúvida. Pois a pergunta já fala exatamente o que vc quer. Mas eu melhorarria para: "Como armazenar o valor do POST em uma variável"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar desta forma:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['variavel'])){
    $variavel = $_POST['variavel'];
}
```

Comment: desta forma ela ira pegar a variavel na mesma pagina e logo em seguida eu posso passar ela?

Comment: o post rolando na mesma pagina ele ira armazenar @LeonardoCosta tentei explicar da forma mais simples possivel ta, caso não tenha entendido peço que de uma boa liga nos tutoriais para entender o funcionamento da linguagem.